# How to count the elements of dataset consists of list

Tags: python, list, count

There is dataset example `A = [[1,3,5],[2,3,5]]`
I want to know the frequency of each element 1,2,3,5 using Counter function.

I want to get the result of `Counter('3':2 ,'5':2, '1':1, '2':2)`

Comment: This isn't valid syntax: `A = {[1,3,5],[2,3,5]}`

Comment: so I mean that there is a dataset consists of list and I want to know the frequency of the element about dataset

Comment: Counter is not a function, it is special purpose dictionary.

Comment: How is the dataset defined?

Comment: The value `2` appears once only, not twice

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

A = [[1,3,5],[2,3,5]]
result = Counter([i for j in A for i in j])
```

the result will be:

```
Counter({1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 2, 2: 1})
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please check the gray button beside the answer and turn it to green :) @tedsong

Answer (score 1):

First of all lists are not hashable, so `A` must not be a set.
So let's make it a list of lists.

Then we apply `Counter` to the sequence obtained by chaining the sublists.

Never reinvent the wheel: itertools provides great solutions

```
import collections as co
import itertools as it

A = [[1,3,5],[2,3,5]]
cnt = co.Counter(it.chain.from_iterable(A))
print(cnt)
```

Produces

```
Counter({3: 2, 5: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a list of list?

`A = [[1,3,5],[2,3,5]]`

if so, you can use numpy to turn this into a flattened array

```
import numpy
#turn A into a numpy array
arr =numpy.array(A)
#get the unique values and their counts - ravel flattens an array
unique,counts = numpy.unique(arr.ravel(),return_counts=True)
my_counts = dict(zip(unique,counts))
my_counts
>>>{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` supports addition and the built-in sum has a [`start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) parameter, i.e. the 0-element for ints. A zero-element for Counters is just `Counter()`. Hence you can solve this via

```
from collections import Counter
A = [[1,2,5], [2, 3, 5]]
sum(Counter(l) for l in A, Counter())
```

gives

```
Counter({1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 2, 2: 1})
```

This can also be solved in terms of Map-Reduce, where `map` is application of `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce

A = [[1,2,5], [2, 3, 5]]
counters = [Counter(l) for l in A]
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, counters)
```

gives

```
Counter({1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 2, 2: 1})
```